Help me optimize common collector transistor amplifier for two quadrant LDO
I need some help with a circuit I can’t find much information online.
Basic function should be a LDO which can source and sink current. To make it a bit more challenging there are some further requirements:

Single supply only
Should also work when near to the VIN rails (see 3 below)
To prevent some cross conduction in the output stage I implemented a common collector amplifier I am not 100 % familiar with. (maybe not even 50%)

Here is the circuit I came up with;

Questions:

Looking at the common collector part of the circuit: Are the resistors around it selected correctly? I have the feeling that base current is pretty high
What can I do to make the common collector part of the circuit more unacceptable to VIN changes? R1 and R11 are now selected to fit to gate voltage threshold for given VIN voltage. But changing the VIN also requires changing these two emitter resistors.

Some additional explanation why I did choose this topology:

Idea gave me an obsolete Maxim patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6437638B1/en

I just have single supply and don’t want to generate an additional voltage to use a NMOS as high side driver like in the patent 1

The output voltage should be adjustable near to the VIN rails, why it made sense to use a PMOS as high side driver and a NMOS as low side driver – which also forbids using a traditional AB linear output stage

EDIT 1:Additional information for Simons comment below showing the switching behavior from on mos to the other:


EDIT 2: Showing gate voltage seperation with voltage source sweep.




With Q3 and Q4 as emitter followers following the the same potential, the gates of M1 and M2 will never be more than 1.4V different. This will ensure that M1 and M2 will be switched on simultaneously, most of the time, causing shoot-through. You'll need some mechanism in place to ensure that this cannot happen. Something that will disable one of the MOSFETs when the other is "active". This is not an issue in a traditional common-drain push-pull output stage, but in this common source configuration it's a problem, unless $V_{IN}$ is smaller than the sum of the two FETs' $V_{GS(TH)}$.

@SimonFitch Thanks for the comment! What you are describing is exactly my issue why I added the emitter followers. My maximum Vin is 5 V - in the simulation (I will add picture to my post above) there is around 2.5 V headroom between the two gate voltages. Assuming I would have higher Vin - is there a solution to this problem that you know from a classic output stage?

You should replace OPAout with a voltage source, and sweep that from 0 to 5V to see the interval in which both FETs are on. That state is not apparent in your simulation, because the op-amp output slews too quickly through that interval.

Also, R2 and R12 keep Q3 and Q4 permanently saturated. I'm not sure what the purpose of those two resistances is, but I think they cause Q3 and Q4 to behave no better than a couple of diodes. I think you'll need a better way to separate the gate potentials.

I added a picture with the requested voltage sweep. Seperation seems to be around 2.3V. I agree with you - there is some room for improvement. But considering the VIN < 5V the actual seperation voltage should be high enough for that case. Do you think I can remove R2 and R12 completely?

I found this circuit which shows a similar topology to mine (at least the output mosfets). Do they use they use the 4 diodes in serios for enough seperation? https://mosfetaudio-didik.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Fig-4.png

Yes, remove R2 and R12. The diodes in your last linked schematic are to bias the push-pull pair of Q10 and Q11, not the MOSFETs.  It seems that when Q10 and Q11 current limits are reached (as sensed by R16 and its unlabelled high-side counterpart), the MOSFETs become biased on, taking over.

The two MOSFETs in your design both have minimum $V_{GS(TH)}$ of 1V. The simulated models are likely above that, and may not exhibit shoot-through, but you should design for worst-case, meaning that you need at least 3V separation of gate potentials. Remove the load V4, and in your MOSFET models set thresholds to 1V. Then plot drain current as you sweep, to see shoot-through.

I did that and can see the shoot-through. Interestingly R2 and R12 will add a significant amount of seperation. With these two resistors = 10k I get around 2.3 V seperation, withouth them 0.8V. Any ideas how to generate the two potentials needed?

Common-collector output stages have voltage gain, so they are a bit trickier to design with than follower output stages. You could add local negative feedback to lower their voltage gain (down to, say, 2x) to make life easier.

Thank you both! I tried that with the local feedback - and I got the 3 V seperation between the gates. But that creates another issue: If I add local feedback I cant reach the required Vgs voltage. As increased the seperation to 3 V I have now limited the maximum Vgs to somewhere below 2V.

@huababua Not that I understood anything I just glanced at, but does your last comment here mean that everything has been resolved?

@periblepsis No, I am still looking for a solution which allows me to use full gate drive voltage while preventing shoot-through by seperating the gate drive voltages enough. Probably not my original question.

@huababua I haven't looked at the patent you mentioned. And I feel like the question and discussion is too deep in the weeds. I can't get a bead on it. LDO is a term that lacks precision, commonly. Could you talk about this project at a higher level for a moment?

@periblepsis I am building a voltage source that can source and sink current. Based on my requirements (lowest possible voltage drop over the pass transistors) I came this common source outout topology which leads to the problem that I need to prevent boths mosfets turning on at the same time.

@huababua I see only ground and a positive rail across the two FETs. I understand class-AB output stages that sink and source but have three rails, not two, or else are driving a load via a capacitor, for example. I know what low dropout means -- very little in-to-out overhead to work with. But I can't think of a DC situation with only ground and a positive rail. Could you elaborate on the details of what this is intended for? My imagination may be a problem that needs a kick. What does this drive?
